# Aren't multi-armed bandits basically the same things as the Von Neumann-Morgenstern utility theorem?

Tags: probability, decision-theory

I can't seem to find any material connecting the two ideas.

How would one who is more knowledgeable about these topics relate them to one another? Is it that multi-armed bandits are just one way of framing the VNM theorem?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you think they are the same?

Comment: @shimao Having learned a bit more about these two ideas - I would correct myself to not ask if they are the same, but rather how they connect. I had thought they were the same idea because the VNM theorem describes a way in which an agent would operate to maximize their reward - which is the same problem faced in multi-armed bandits.